# Redefinition of structure

Tags: c

Below is the code of my header file trie.h.
The compiler keep showing the following error:

```
In file included from speller.c:11:
./trie.h:3:8: error: redefinition of 'letter'
struct letter
       ^
./trie.h:3:8: note: previous definition is here
struct letter
       ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [speller.o] Error 1
```

The code:

```
struct letter
{
    int is_word;
    struct letter* arr[27];
};


// fuctions
struct letter* create_trie();
void free_trie(struct letter* trie);
```

Comment: Does your header have include guards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your file gets included multiple times, hence the redefinition error.
To avoid this problem use [**include guards**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard):

```
#ifndef HEADERNAME_DEFINED
#define HEADERNAME_DEFINED

// your code goes here.

#endif // HEADERNAME_DEFINED
```

or you can use non-standard preprocessor directive like [`#pragma once`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4141z1cx.aspx) to do the job. It results in less code, and sometimes faster compilation speed.
Put that on top of your file:

```
#pragma once

// your code goes here
```

**Note:** *The comment (`// HEADERNAME_DEFINED` part) after `#endif` isn't necessary. It is just a hint for programmer to know what belongs together.*

Comment: Thanks. Multiple inclusion was my problem.

Comment: @ArpanMangal glad it resolved your problem. If that's the case, you can mark the answer as accepted.